# Split NSString into components

Tags: objective-c

I have an object which contains the NSString value.

NSString *string =@"50 ,50";

i want to separate this string between the ",",I also want to store "50" and @"50" into different substring. How this is possible can anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use:

componentsSeparatedByString:

Comment: can you please give me an example

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
NSString *string = @"50,50";
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeperatedByString:@","];
```

This way you will have `@"50"` and `@"50"` in the `components` array.